# CMake nested OBJECT library dependencies

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I created a project with some nested library dependencies using the `OBJECT` library type. The motivation for this is to avoid link order issues with static libraries.

I have a simple directory structure as follows:

```
├── bar
│   ├── bar.c
│   └── bar.h
├── foo
│   ├── foo.c
│   └── foo.h
├── main.c
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

`foo` depends on `bar`, and `main` depends on `foo`. For example,

bar.c

```c
#include "bar.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void) {
  printf("woot woot\n");
}
```

foo.c

```c
#include "foo.h"

#include "bar.h"

void foo(void) {
  bar();
}
```

main.c

```c
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt

```sh
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(myproj)

enable_language(C ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# build bar
add_library(bar OBJECT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar/bar.c)
target_include_directories(bar PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar)

# build foo, depends on bar
add_library(foo OBJECT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo/foo.c)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)

# build executable, depends on foo
add_executable(myexe ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)
target_link_libraries(myexe PUBLIC foo)
```

My expectation is that `myexe` would inherit the `bar` dependency from `foo` when it links to it. However, this is not the case it seems. When the code is compiled, `main.o` only links to `foo.o`, and thus there is an undefined reference to `bar`. However, if I change the library types from `OBJECT` to `STATIC` everything works fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: There is no reason to use `enable_language`... just say `project(myproj LANGUAGES C ASM)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Object libraries cannot be chained this way. You must link *directly* (not transitively) to an object library to acquire its object files. As it says in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries),

> Object Libraries may "link" to other object libraries to get usage requirements, but since they do not have a link step nothing is done with their object files. [...] In other words, when Object Libraries appear in a target's `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property they will be treated as Interface Libraries, but when they appear in a target's `LINK_LIBRARIES` property their object files will be included in the link too.

I agree it defies all reason, though.

---

However, you can manually propagate the object files via `target_link_libraries(INTERFACE)` and the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` generator expression as of 3.21 (doing so was buggy in earlier versions, and the even-hacker `target_sources` may be used in earlier versions, too).

Do note that this is a bit of a hack, since there are some cases that will break. Notably, if a library target links to such a target publicly, then the object files will propagate *again*. So... be careful.

Still, here's a corrected version of your example build:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myproj LANGUAGES C ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11 CACHE STRING "The C standard to use")
option(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED "Enforce strict C standard selection" ON)
option(CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS "Allow compiler-specific C extensions" OFF)

# build bar
add_library(bar OBJECT bar/bar.c)
target_include_directories(
  bar PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar>"
)

# build foo, depends on bar
add_library(foo OBJECT foo/foo.c)
target_include_directories(
  foo PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo>"
)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar "$<TARGET_OBJECTS:bar>")

# build executable, depends on foo
add_executable(myexe main.c)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE foo)
```

At the command line:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build 
...
$ cmake --build build -- -nv
[1/4] /usr/bin/cc  -I/path/to/bar -std=c11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar/bar.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar/bar.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar/bar.c.o -c /path/to/bar/bar.c
[2/4] /usr/bin/cc  -I/path/to/foo -I/path/to/bar -std=c11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo/foo.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo/foo.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo/foo.c.o -c /path/to/foo/foo.c
[3/4] /usr/bin/cc  -I/path/to/foo -I/path/to/bar -std=c11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o -c /path/to/main.c
[4/4] : && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo/foo.c.o CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.c.o -o myexe  CMakeFiles/bar.dir/./bar/bar.c.o && :
```

Comment: I solved the problem by following this strategy, with the added step of creating an `INTERFACE` library wrapper for transitive inclusion of the object files and their usage requirements. This made it work even with a parent library target that linked to it publicly. See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#linking-object-libraries-via-target-objects)

Comment: @JeffL - glad I could point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I tried using the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS>` method to transitively combine object files into `libfoo.a` and found that the `bar_impl` object library at the end of the dependency chain (`libfoo.a -> OBJECT bar -> OBJECT bar_impl`) didn't appear in the `libfoo.a`. I think this is because the static library has no linking step. It seems this method works for shared libraries & executables, but not static libraries. This is counter to my expectations.